# ClientException 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel-5.3, guzzle6, laravel-passport

I don't know why my code doesn't work ,I'm trying to connect two api

In api 1 :

```
    $token = "my-token";
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'http:.../testHeaders', [
        'headers'        => ['Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => $token],
    ]);

    $resBody = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($res->getBody());
    return response()->json($resBody,$res->getStatusCode());
```

In api 2 :

```
Route::get('testHeaders',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    return response()->json([
        'Accept' => $request->header('Accept'),
        'Authorization' => $request->header('Authorization')
        ],200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

PS: When i send headers (Authorisation and Accept) with postman it works,
And also when I remove the middleware it wotks !!!

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I launched an api with wamp and the other with php artisan serve and it works